# ruby check whether string in csv will be mistaken for a date (in excel)

Tags: ruby, excel, date, csv

I have a function in my Rails app that creates a csv. When the user opens that csv in Excel many times there are fields that excel changes like:

```
1-3
```

becomes

```
Jan-3
```

I can easily overcome this issue by using the solution outlined here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/491295-opening-csv-how-to-tell-excel-string-is-not-a-date.html

```
csvarray.push('="'+result_item.send(column).to_s+'"')
```

The field in the csv becomes:

```
="1-3"
```

But would like to convert only the fields that Excel gets wrong and not all the fields.

I started by doing a:

```
.match(/-/)
```

but I am wondering if there is a better and more exclusive way to find the offending fields.

Any ideas?

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2.12

EDIT: Combining both @Agis and @Mori's answers seems to cover most of the examples I have come across:

```
def col_is_date?(value)
  (!!(Date.parse(value) rescue nil)) || ((value =~ /\A\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\z/) === 0)
end
```

I am not sure who to award the "correct" answer to...

EDIT 2: regarding the two correct answers I defer to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196341/combination-of-two-answers-is-the-correct-answer

Comment: You could specify that a digit must come before and after the `-`.

Comment: What do the "offending" fields look like? Give us more examples that cover all the possibilities.

Comment: @Agis I believe you have found the crux of the issue. I do not know all the possibilities and have been unable to find a full (or even partial) list.

Comment: @paulguy Then a regular expression that you will adapt gradually is the way to go imho. Think about what you want to *allow*, not what you want to *disallow* (ie. a whitelist approach). Using `Date#parse` is *unecessary* if you know what values you want to allow.

Comment: @Agis I think adapting the regular expression is a great idea and will be a necessary step going forward. However, I think there are too many date formats to think of and building a regular expression from scratch to cover all of them would be a waste of time. `Date#parse` cover a wide base and the regular expression is a required supplement. The key part of your latest comment is _if you know what values you want to allow_ Thanks again!

Comment: @paulguy So you don't have a *specific*, *well-defined* format that you want to allow as input?

Comment: @Agis I may be getting confused by what you are asking. Any input is allowed. I just take the given value, try to guess if excel will (seemingly arbitrarily) change that field, and if so then modify the value so excel will not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my edits I found the combination of the two answers to be what I needed or "correct" and again referring to this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196341/combination-of-two-answers-is-the-correct-answer I believe the next step is to answer my own question with the combined answer.

```
def col_is_date?(value)
  (!!(Date.parse(value) rescue nil)) || ((value =~ /\A\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\z/) === 0)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def col_is_date?(value)
  !!(Date.parse(value) rescue nil)
end
```

Comment: I like this but it does not work for the example I provided "1-3".

Answer (score 2):

You should be *explicit* and specify what values you want to allow:

```
regexp = /\A\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\z/

'1-1'   =~ regexp # => 0
'Jan-1' =~ regexp # => nil
```

This regular expression will match everything that *starts with one to two digits, followed by a `-`, followed (and ending) with one to two digits*.